# Authority section in DNS packet contains only NS records?

Tags: networking, dns, network-protocols

I'm new to DNS and I'm trying to understand the DNS packet format. From what I understand, the authority section of a DNS packet gives information about servers that are authoritative for the domain name in question. From playing around with dig on UNIX (and from intuition), it seems as though records in the authority section are always NS records. However, I couldn't find confirmation of this anywhere. Is this correct? If not, what does it mean for an authority record to not be an NS record?

Answer (score 0):

In DNS, a single DNS server instance is responsible ("Authoritative") for a given domain.

Since DNS stores records for DNS servers as NS records, the Authority section of the datagram will always be an NS record.

From [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) section 4.1 (page 24):

> the authority section contains RRs that point toward an authoritative
>   name server;

https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ns-record/

Comment: Usually, 2 or more servers are authoritative for a domain. See [RFC 2182](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2182)'s definition of "Secondary Server".